# How to show a custom uialertview created in interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, customization, uialertview

I've created a custom uialertview in ib, with two button and a textfield.
Then i create a .h and a .m in this way:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DialogWelcome : UIAlertView{
    IBOutlet UITextField *text;
    UIButton *ok;
    UIButton *annulla;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *text;
- (IBAction)ok:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)annulla:(id)sender;
@end
```

and .m :

```
#import "DialogWelcome.h"

@implementation DialogWelcome
@synthesize text;

-(IBAction)ok:(id)sender{

}
-(IBAction)annulla:(id)sender{

}

@end
```

i've not implement methods cause in first i need to show it!
i call this in viewcontroller in this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    DialogWelcome *alert = [[DialogWelcome alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" 
                                                message:nil 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC*2.0);
    dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    });

    [alert release];
}
```

This will show a normal uialertview empty with a title. why it doesn't show my custom uialertview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [*UIAlertView Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

So, what you're trying to do is explicitly not allowed.

Comment: Try using a modal view.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html